# Miami travel in mid December 2017

Tags: event-based-effects, miami

I am scheduling a trip to Miami in December after hurricane Irma. Is this a good idea for tourists? Will clean up efforts still be taking place?

Answer (score 1):

Me think that in the more touristic areas, the clean up will be near fully  completed by december.

Those areas bring in a lot of money to the local economy; so they need to do it faster.

In less touristic areas, the cleanup will be slower, but will be mostly does for public places (commercial streets...)

See this for a summary of cleanup efforts by areas.

http://www.miamiherald.com/news/weather/hurricane/article176043006.html